# Measure & integration vs Complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

If I want to go down a statistics (masters degree) track that's a bit heavy on the math side, and I had to choose between complex analysis and measure theory as a course which one should I take and why?

Thanks you very much!

Comment: If you had to pick one, I think it would be measure theory inasmuch as it relates to probability.

Comment: Measure theory without a doubt- you can study what complex analysis you may need on your own. After the initial torment with measure theory, you will be able to "see through" any theoretical or practical application and really understand (and so judge or criticize) their probabilistic base. Because without a firm probabilistic base, statistics is just descriptive mathematical approximations under another name.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest measure theory for the following reasons:

- Complex analysis is based on it
- Probability theory is based on it (again closer to your main subjects)
- I found it much more useful for mathematical understanding (I consider complex analysis as somewhat much calculation and little mathematical work, Stokes' theorem from measure theory gives most theorems of complex analysis as mere "applications")

Comment: While I fully agree that measure theory is much more relevant for probability, I don't understand how complex analysis is based on measure theory, I wouldn't call Stokes thm a measure theory result, and while Cauchy thm + int. formula are its consequences, they are not 'most theorems' of cpx. analysis